# Can I use arduino USART tx and rx separatly?

Tags: arduino, serial, uart

My idea is to receive GPS sentences in the RX pin, parse the data and send the result to my computer via the TX pin. (with same baud rate. 9600 for instance)

Is it possible or may I encounter buffer issue for non-consume bytes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RS-232 is really two separate serial lines, one in each direction.  Likewise, UART hardware is independent for receiving and transmitting, except for the baud rate generator.  So as long as you want to use the same baud rate (which you do), there should be no problem.  Think about it.  The micro just sees a RX and TX line.  It has no way of knowing whether they are connected to the RX and TX of one other device, or split so that TX goes to the RX of one device, and RX goes to TX of another.  How would you imagine it could tell the difference?

Of course if the higher level protocols for either of those devices is bi-directional, then this won't work.  If you just want to pass GPS bytes along to your computer, that would work.  However, if the GPS needs to be sent something to get it going or otherwise needs to be controlled, then it won't work.

Comment: The GPS device i use has a mode were it only use its tx pin

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible, as long as you don't expect to multiplex the two devices. Whether it is advisable or not, is quite another matter entirely.

So, just wire up the RX pin to the GPS and the TX pin to the PC. You will not be able to transmit to the GPS nor receive from the PC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could probably do this, but is there only one UART available?
If so, and you would like be able to send and receive from either/both PC or GPS, then you could maybe look into [bit-banging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging) a second UART.

Comment: The arduino device has only one UART available.